# animate colour by using css3

Tags: css, css-transitions

It will be possible to obtain animate colour just by using css3?

Here is the demo about the effect I would like to obtain [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3WHAS/4/).
The demo is using `jquery.color.js`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.replace-bg-on-hover').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#333"
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#6CA2FF"
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Someone's probably going to kill me for this, but here's something to get you started: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp <- Otherwise w3schools sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css3 transitions for this. Here's a quick example - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sS7Ud/3/)

Code from my example:

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>​
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #005ca1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
    background: #000;
}
```

Edit: Added the rest of the prefixes.

Comment: if you do so, your transition will only work on webkit broswers (ie safari & chrome) ; see my answer to get all the prefixes to add.

Comment: That's correct. I used webkit as an example, but the rest of the prefixes should of course be added.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do it. You set a :hover color for the background and you don't forget to add the transition css property to the element :

CSS code :

```
.myElementToHover{
    background: #c00;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease
}

.myElementToHover:hover{
    background: #00c;
}
```

Generally speaking, when you want to use a CSS3 rule, Paul Irish (jquery) made a very usefull page : http://css3please.com/ Just use it, all the answers are here ! (except that you should now add the -ms- prefix).

With this code, you add a transition for every css property, but if you want to add a transition for only the backgroundColor, you replace 'all' by 'backgroundColor'.

0.5s is the duration of the animation. It can also be set in ms.

ease is the way the animation behave. Basic settings are :

```
linear
ease (default)
ease-in
ease-out
ease-in-out
```

But you can set your own transition :

```
cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)
```

Matthew Lein made a very nice page to help you make a custom easing settings : http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/